# How do I shut down executor when using it with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading

Here I am invoking three threads, the second and third threads waits for the first thread to complete and then starts executing in parallel. If I use `executor.shutdown()` then only the first task executes. I want to know how to shutdown executor after all my threads are done executing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In main");      
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);     
        CompletableFuture<Void> thenCompose = supplyAsync(() -> doTask1(), executor)
        .thenCompose(resultOf1 -> allOf(
                runAsync(() -> doTask2(resultOf1), executor),
                runAsync(() -> doTask3(), executor)
        ));
        //executor.shutdown();      
        System.out.println("Exiting main");
    }

    private static void doTask3() {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(3);
        }

    }

    private static void doTask2(int num) {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(num);
        }

    }

    private static int doTask1() {
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(1);
        }
        return 5;

    }
```

> Output With `executor.shutdown()`

```
In main
Exiting main
11111
```

> Output Without `executor.shutdown()`

```
In main
Exiting main
111113535353535
But the program doesn't terminates.
```

Comment: I would try by adding a final task to the CompletableFuture `.thenRun(() -> { executor.shutdown(); });`

Comment: Thanks you, its worked. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try by adding a final task to the CompletableFuture

`.thenRun(() -> { executor.shutdown(); });`

Comment: What if I'm expecting an output from the supplyAsync call instead of Void?

Comment: Then you would not add this line. On a separate line you would do `thenCompose.get()` to retrieve your result, and just after that, `executor.shutdown()`. Since `get()` will wait until the `CompletableFuture` has finished, you can safely shutdown the executor afterwards.

Comment: Is it recommended to `shutdown()` or what could happen if not using `executor.shutdown()` post `get()`?

Comment: @Nobita prolly the same behaviour as OP, the program never exits.

Comment: What do you mean by OP here?

Comment: @Nobita OP stands for Original poster, Im refering to the same problem described in this post